# How to have a button change the form within the subform "window" in Ms Access

Tags: forms, ms-access

I need to create my own "navigation" form in Ms Access.  Basically, I have a MAIN form that has one field named LotNumSelect

Then, buttons representing each form the user would like to view.
Button1 - Customer
Button2 - Job Data

etc.

Once the customer clicks a button, the procedure would open the corresponding form in the subform window to the record matching the LotNumSelect field.

So far, I have this.

```
Private Sub ContactInfo_Click()
Main_Customer_Sbfm.SourceObject = "Main_Customer_Sbfm"
Forms!Form1!Main_Customer_Sbfm.Form!Lot_Number.SetFocus
```

This nicely switches the form within the subform.  the problem is how do I get the form within the subform find the record associated with the data in the LotNumSelect Field?

I tried this..

```
DoCmd.FindRecord LotNumSelect.Value, acEntire, , acSearchAll
```

but it's giving me a runtime error of "2162"

"A macro set to one of the current field's properties failed because of an error in a FindRecord action argument.

Comment: You can set the subform "Link Master" and "Link Child" fields to a key that will link your main forms data to the subforms data.

Comment: OK, fixed.  I didn't realize that I hadn't added a bound field representing the masterfield data.  Duh....   Thanks for your help.